# validate phone number before saving

Tags: java

I have here a code to validate a phone number

```
public class ValidatePhoneNumber {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        String phoneNumber = "1-(80..2)-321-0361";
        System.out.println(phoneNumber.length());
        String regex = "^\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form XXX-XXXXXXX");
        }
    }
}
```

How can i put this code inside the SAVEBUTTON ACTION?

```
private void saveButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {...}
```

to prevent the user for saving invalid phone number format

THANK YOU!

Comment: Based on the the information that you've given, its difficult to answer your question. But you'll need some way to retrieve the phone number from within your action, and then some way to either approve or disapprove of the phone number so the application can save it or alert the user if there's a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new in java. All i want to do is to prevent the user from saving invalid phone number format. Do u have any suggestion

Comment: hi @mix, in case you found my answer useful, can you please accept it? it has been 3 years since then ... :)

Answer (score 4):

Supposing you are writing your code within a class `public class Inventory extends javax.swing.JFrame` (as you specified in your comment), I would write an `ActionListener` to handle the button click event

```
public class Inventory extends javax.swing.JFrame
    private String currPhoneNumber; // it may contains something like "1-(80..2)-321-0361"

    ...

    // this code can be *within* your class, but *outside* any method declaration
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println(currPhoneNumber.length());
        String regex = "^\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(currPhoneNumber);
      }

      if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form XXX-XXXXXXX");

        // throw an exception or do something that will prevent the data to be 
        // saved (what to do here really depends on the application you are writing)
      }

    }

    ...

    private void createMyFancyInterface(...) { 
        ...
        JButton source = new JButton("Do something");
        source.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively (as someone underlined) you can use anonymous classes, thus reducing it to the following:

```
public class Inventory extends javax.swing.JFrame
    private String currPhoneNumber; // it may contains something like "1-(80..2)-321-0361"

    ...

    // this code can be *within* your class, but *outside* any method declaration
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println(currPhoneNumber.length());
        String regex = "^\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(currPhoneNumber);
      }

      if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form XXX-XXXXXXX");

        // throw an exception or do something that will prevent the data to be 
        // saved (what to do here really depends on the application you are writing)
      }

    }

    ...

    private void createMyFancyInterface(...) { 
        ...
        JButton source = new JButton("Do something");
        source.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
             // the same code as ButtonListener.actionPerformed above
             ...
          }
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use an anonymous class.

Comment: Hello @FSp thank you for answering my question, But I want to clarify if this
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    // your code here ....

  }
}

should be put inside the 
public class Inventory extends javax.swing.JFrame 
and outside the
private void saveButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {...}
sorry I'm new in java :(

Comment: @mix the short answer to your question is: yes. i provided a more detailed example, hope it clarifies

Comment: hello again. Thank u for the clear explanation for a beginner like me :)
I just want to ask is currPhoneNumber ( the name of my phone number field?)

Comment: @mix in my example it is `currPhoneNumber` is just a `String`. if you make it a `TextField` you must read its content as `currPhoneNumber.getText()` (but it is conceptually equivalent)

Comment: @FSp I wonder how it will be passed on my phone number field. I build it using Jframe.

Comment: here is my phone number field
private void saveButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            
    
        String supphonef = supPhoneField.getText();
based on your code how it supposedly know that it is for supPhoneField ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to do this.

```
class JavaApplication extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextArea area;
    JButton button;
    JTextField box;
    JPanel panel;

    public JavaApplication19() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        area = new JTextArea(26, 30);
        box = new JTextField(30);
        button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(area);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(box);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String phoneNumber = area.getText();
        System.out.println(phoneNumber);
        String regex = "^\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            box.setText("Phone Number Valid");
        } else {
            box.setText("Phone Number must be in the form XXX-XXXXXXX");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication pad = new JavaApplication();
        pad.setSize(500, 500);
        pad.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @john thank you for providing me an answer. I just want to clarify seems I'm new in java, I cannot understand well. the code you showed above, should I put them inside

private void saveButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {...}